# Python window does not open in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a Python script that I need to run in the Python window. When I click on the Python window icon, nothing happens. I expect a window to open up which allows Python commands to be entered. I think this may be due to removing additional monitors. Maybe the Python window is opening on a phantom monitor?

Is there a way for me to get the window back on the main monitor?

Answer (score 3):

After closing ArcMap, try renaming the Normal.mxt file, then re-open ArcMap. Normal.mxt is often found in a folder like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.4\ArcMap\Templates`. This will cause ArcMap to generate a new Normal.mxt based on the computer's current configuration.

All settings for the ArcMap interface will be set back to default, so you will have to redo them also.

Comment: If the mxd had the custom option to "save all changes to the document", you will have to uncheck that before erasing normal.mxt.

Comment: Resetting your ArcGIS application profile  < geonet article
https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile